# Sql to show total hours on time card with sum for the whole month

Tags: sql-server, kronos-workforce-central

I need help in SQL to get the total hours worked on the time card if possible sum it for the entire pay period.

Here is the command i have built right now but i dont know why its not displaying the record

```
select personid, personnum, DURATIONDAYSQTY/3600 as amount, CURRPAYPERIODEND 
from VP_EMPLOYEEV42
left join [dbo].WFCTOTAL on [dbo].WFCTOTAL.EMPLOYEEID = [dbo].[VP_EMPLOYEEV42].PERSONID
where HOMELABORLEVELNM1 = 'JP' and PAYCODEID in('1167','1163');
```

I hope that you can guide me on how i can make the effective date from the start of the pay period to end so that it would only capture the hours of the employees per pay period.

I also need to display as an output the total hours of the employees in one line example 200 hours for the entire month of January

sample screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zubHx.png)

the above screenshot is the source and my expected output is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEunt.png)

thanks a lot

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results (both as tabular text) to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Hi @DrinCastronero, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a tag for a database you use. It means a lot. Thanks!

Comment: How to Ask Question??  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: hi guys thank you so much for your patience and understanding sorry if i didnt provide the details i was using my mobile phone and i didnt have the files there

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Comment: I got it already

Comment: a clarification i want is why i cant specify the startdtm and enddtm to the format i want how can i use it so that when i run the interface it prompts it and it uses the date for start and end date after the user types it in

Comment: here is the updated command i used  SELECT [PERSONNUM]
      ,DURATIONSECSQTY/3600 as amount
      ,[APPLYDTM]
      ,[PAYCODEID]
      ,[STARTDTM]
      ,[ADJSTARTDTM]
      ,[ADJAPPLYDTM]
      ,[ENDDTM]
    FROM [dbo].[WFCTOTAL]
 left join [dbo].[VP_employeev42] on [dbo].[VP_employeev42].[PERSONID] = [dbo].[WFCTOTAL].EMPLOYEEID
  where paycodeid in ('1167','1163')
 order by PERSONNUM